# how to use controllers and actions authorization at the same time

Tags: cakephp, controller, authorization, acl

I'm a newbie in cakephp and I'm trying to build an application from the scratch. I'm reading the manual and also I did the tutorials.

Right now I'm facing an issue about authorization: How allow the users to do an action (edit,delete,...) but only if it's their own thing (post,events,...), using ActionsAuthorize and ControllersAuthorize at the same time. Maybe it's a silly question but as a newbie I have the feeling that I'm missing something.

If the application were simpler it would be enough using just ControllersAuthorize (isAuthorized())  but I find ActionsAuthorize pretty useful.

Following the example from the tutorial (Blog), each Post has an author (User) and belongs to a Profile (author,administrator,editor,...), users in general can edit posts ($this->Acl->allow('author','controllers/Posts/edit')) but only their own posts.

So far I have the following code:

```
//User Model
public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'both'));
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Profile' => array(
        'className' => 'Profile',
        'foreignKey' => 'profile_id'
    )
);
//saving the aro alias => username   
public function aftersave($created) {
    if($created) {
        $this->Aro->save(array('alias'=>$this->data[$this->alias]['username']));
    }
}

public function parentNode() {
    if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)) {
        return null;
    }
    if (isset($this->data['User']['profile_id'])) {
        $profileId = $this->data['User']['profile_id'];
    } else {
        $profileId = $this->field('profile_id');
    }
    if (!$profileId) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return array('Profile' => array('id' => $profileId));
    }
}

//Profile Model
public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'both'));
public function parentNode() {
    return null;
}
//savin the aco alias => name
public function aftersave($created) {
    if($created) {
        $this->Aro->save(array('alias'=>$this->data[$this->alias]['name']));
    }
}

//Post Model
public function isOwnedBy($post, $user) {
    return $this->field('id', array('id' => $post, 'user_id' => $user)) === $post;
}

//Post Controller
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('index');
}       
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // All registered users can add posts
    if ($this->action === 'add' && isset($user)) {
        return true;
    }
    // The owner of a post can edit and delete it
    if (in_array($this->action, array('edit', 'delete'))) {
        $postId = $this->request->params['pass'][0];
        if ($this->Post->isOwnedBy($postId, $user['id'])) {
            //after knowing if the post is owned by the user check ACL
            return $this->Acl->check($user['profile_id'],$this->Acl->aco,$this->action);
        }
    }
    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}

//AppController
public $components = array(
    'Acl',
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array('Blowfish'),
        'authError' => 'You are not allow to perform this action, please login',
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index')
    )
);
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // Only admins can access admin functions
    if (isset($user['profile_id']) && isset($this->request->params['admin'])) {
        return (bool)($user['profile_id'] === '1');
    }
    // Admin can access every action
    if (isset($user['profile_id']) && $user['profile_id'] === '1') {
        return true;
    }       
    return false;
}       
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller');
    $this->Auth->allow('display');
}  
        // The owner of a post can edit and delete it
        if (in_array($this->action, array('edit', 'delete','view'))) {
            $postId = $this->request->params['pass'][0];
            if ($this->Post->isOwnedBy($postId, $user['id'])) {
                return $this->Acl->check($user['profile_id'],$this->Acl->aco,$this->action);
            }
        }
        return parent::isAuthorized($user);
    }
```

So my question is if I'm using correctly the authorization in the way I'm using it in PostController:isAutorized(): first checking if the user owns the post and then checking if the user is allow to the action. Is it another way? This way is good? There's a better way? Am I missing something?

Thank you so much in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to get it done. 
Edit: Realized you are doing ACL app. This is the answer if you're not. Figured it still might be useful since no else has responded.

```
public function doStuff(){
      if(AuthComponent::user('role') == 'admin'){
      //do stuff 
      }elseif(AuthComponent::user('id') == $blogpost['Blog']['owner']){ 
      // do stuff 
      }else{ 
      $this->Html->redirect(array('action' => 'elsewhere'));
      }


 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer at the end I didn't use ACL. And only used ControllerAuthorize.  It was more simple checking who own what instead using ACL.